Safari strange issue with flex and column and grids
Can anyone explain to me if this is a bug or what that I should report to safari team
In any browser except Safari I get the proper rendering :
https://play.tailwindcss.com/uzqrEtPtKX
<div class="flex min-h-screen flex-col flex-wrap">
  <div class="grid gap-5 grid-cols-2">
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>World</div>
    <div>World</div>
  </div>
</div>

But in Safari the objects are spread along the page, I don't understand why.
